# @ControllerAdvice does not redirect 404 page after exception in Spring boot mvc

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am using @Controlleradvice but id does not work, I don't know why.
it is @Controlleradvice:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MainControllerAdvice {
    private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainControllerAdvice.class);

    @ExceptionHandler(value = DataNotFoundException.class)
    public String handleNotFound(){
        return "not-found";
    }
}
```

custom exception:

```
@ResponseStatus(value= HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason="No such data")
public class DataNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
    public DataNotFoundException() {
        super();
    }
}
```

and controller:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/details/{id}")
public String details(@PathVariable Integer id, Model model) throws DataNotFoundException {
    Pupil pupil = pupilService.get(id);
    if (pupil == null) {
        throw new DataNotFoundException();
    }
    model.addAttribute("pupil", pupil);
    return "details";
}
```

what I am doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to return a view name and get it rendered to display the custom error page. If you're using server side template engine such as `Thymeleaf` in spring boot application, then add the custom pages in templates folder and make the following changes.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MainControllerAdvice {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = DataNotFoundException.class)
    public ModelAndView handleNotFound() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("not-found");
        return modelAndView;
    }

}
```

Place the custom error page in the `templates` folder with the same name as set in the `ModelAndView` object.

[image]

Spring starter dependecy for `thymeleaf`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```